# CS8509 is reported by IntelliSense but not the C# compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

C# CS8509 warning is about the switch expression not being exhaustive. My Visual Studio reports this warning as error in IntelliSense but not during the build. The build still fails with MSBuild though. What could be the reason that VS is not reporting this error?

The problem happens on both Version 17.4.4 and 17.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was skipped during the build. Clean, Rebuilding, closing and restarting Visual Studio did not help.

Removing the project from the solution and adding it back fixed the problem.

Comment: Assuming your project was under version control, was there a diff after you removed and re-added it?

Comment: @DrewNoakes The solution is under version control. Removing and adding fixed individual projects but there were too many to fix. I ended up resetting and redoing all the changes to the solution file and the project files that fixed the problem. Looks like the solution file was corrupted and rather than reporting the problem, Visual Studio swallowed the error and skipped the build instead. Bad design decision in my opinion and has been reported before but wasn't addressed. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/solution-and-project-builds-are-skipping-all-but-o/867438